# How can I change CSS paddingclass for collapsed Items?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, bootstrap-5, padding

I have a simple navbar, mostly copypasta'd from Bootstrap's navbar tutorial.

Basically, I put padding on a form using the Bootstrap class "pe-5" (I only used pe-5 to demonstrate this better, I will probably reduce it if I can fix this), so it's aligned to the right of the navbar with some space from the edge of the screen, and a collapsible button that appears when the form is flex wrapped (please excuse my vocabulary as I am new to both webdev and bootstrap (and flexbox)). However, when the button is collapsed (so when I shrink the window until the button appears, and then click the collapse button), the padding is still there on the form input and search button and it looks weird and off.

Is there a way to change the CSS for collapsed items? I've tried many things, including changing the CSS for when the collapse is shown:

```
#navbarCollapse.navbar-collapse.collapse.show #top-search-form {
padding-left: 0rem;
padding-right: 0rem; 
}
```

However nothing seemed to change. And I'm fairly certain I have the CSS path correct as changing the margins seems have an effect but changes it while the animation starts so it looks like it "jumps" as it is collapsing. Regardless, changing the padding does nothing. I've also tried a few other CSS methods that I can't remember off the top of my head.

I also tried using Javascript but it became extremely messy and I feel like there is a much simpler solution. What I tried was adding event listeners for when the collapsible button was shown and hidden and would add/remove the pe-5 class using classList.remove(), but I ran into a problem that when resizing the window, if the button is collapsed but hidden, it is still considered "collapsed" and the bootstrap padding class would still be removed. Then I tried adding an event listener to window resize and it became very messy and I could not get it to work as intended as finding if an element is overflown through flex is a lot harder than I thought, and I figured this would end up slowing my page down significantly.

Here is an example of the issue I am having:
https://jsfiddle.net/jbu812os/
Just shrink the screen until the collapse hamburger button appears and click it and it should show that the input search box and search button are not taking up the full collapse width.
Any help would be GREATLY appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Not enough debugging details, don't link to a fiddle put the code here, and have you tried looking in the browser devtools?

Comment: I was debugging using the devtools for about an hour, but your comment gave me an idea that led to me solving a big part of my problem, so thank you very much! Just out of curiosity, why not post jsfiddle? When I was researching this issue, about half the StackOverflow posts had jsfiddle links. I suppose mine isnt that much code to post, but should I save jsfiddle for larger stuff? Anyways, cheers! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help. The reason we discourage **having only** a jsfiddle is that the link could go down and future visitors with your problem who arrived here by search engine will not be able to see what your issue was. By all means have one to supplement a stack overflow snippet if it's a large project, but then again try and find the minimal code with the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding these two jQuery event handlers:

```
$('#navbarCollapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('#top-search-form').removeClass('pe-5')
})

$('#navbarCollapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('#top-search-form').addClass('pe-5')
})
```

I am using the built in Bootstrap events and they seem to work. And for the resize issue, you can still use the window.resize event. Something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if($(window).width > 300) {
    $('#navbarCollapse').collapse('hide')
  }
})
```

This will force your collapse component to hide whenever your screen size is greater than 300px.

Comment: I am not sure why jQuery is not working properly for me (yes the js comes before BS). However, I just typed out the regular javascript version of this and it worked great! The only problem was resizing of the window. But after some debugging I found that the .navbar-toggler class display attribute returns 'none' if it is not displayed and 'block' if it is showing (returns all strings). For those trying to figure this out it's important to note that this is a computed style so use const el = document.querySelector(.navbar-toggler') then getComputedStyle(el). If it returns 'none', add, else rem.

Comment: I sure hate how comments work on StackOverflow. Wanted to explain the other part of the problem I had and post my solution but ran out of text. Also wanted to say THANK YOU! I'll try to get jQuery working and edit my original post with a jQuery and regular javascript solution. Thank you for the help I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Upvoted, but try and avoid jQuery especially in 2022